# UIStackView frame size not editable in storyboard

Tags: storyboard, uikit, uistackview

I have a simple `UIStackView` (with two equally spaced `UIButton`'s horizontally) constrained to the bottom of the scene with a height of 30.  I am unable to change the width or height because the options are simply greyed out in Storyboard's Size Inspector.  I have tried deleting all the constrained, deleting the contained elements and a number of basic things that might cause this to happen but nothing seems to fix this problem.

All the views in my Scene are properly constrained and they all have editable frames.  What property or factor could be causing this to happen?